# Can the map and overview map be split into two html?

Tags: openlayers

I need to create maps and overview maps using openlayers.

The map html is included in the c# chromium (cefsharp) controller.

However, since the map and the overview map must be displayed in different chromium windows, two html must be created.

The map and the overview must be linked. 
(When moving the coordinates of the map, the coordinates of the overview map must also be moved.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at this solution: [ol-ext: Extensions for OpenLayers](https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/misc/map.synchro.html)

```
<html>

<head>
    <!----------------------------------------------------------
    Copyright (c) 2015-2018 Jean-Marc VIGLINO,
    released under CeCILL-B (french BSD like) licence: http://www.cecill.info/
    ------------------------------------------------------------>
    <title>ol-ext: Synchronized windows</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>

    <link href="https://openlayers.org/en/v5.2.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />   
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v5.2.0/build/ol.js"></script>   
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL,Object.assign"></script>

    <div class="info">
        This example synchronize maps in different windows.
        <br /> The WSynchro object do the job: WSynchro.synchronize will dispatch a synchro event.
        <br />
        <button onclick="openWin();">Open a new window!</button>
    </div>
    <div id="map" class="map" style="width:600px; height:400px;"></div>
    <style>        
        .info {
            background:#f5f5f5;
            padding:0.5em;
            margin: 1em 0;
         }
        #map {
            float: left;
            margin-right: 1em;
            background: #ddd;
        }
    </style>

    <script>

        /** WSynchro object to synchronize windows
         *  - windows: array of windows to synchro (
         *  - source: the window source (undefined if first window)
         */
        if (!window.WSynchro) {
            var WSynchro = {
                windows: []
            }
        }

        /** Open a new window to synchronize
         *  @param {url|undefined} url to open, default current window url
         *  @param {specs|undefined|null} specs (as for window.open), undefined to open in a new window, null to open in a new tab, default new window
         */
        WSynchro.open = function (href, specs) {
            var w = window.open(href || window.location.href, "_blank", typeof (specs) == "undefined" ? "location=1,menubar=1,toolbar=1,scrollbars=1" : specs);
            if (!w.WSynchro) w.WSynchro = {
                windows: [window],
                source: window
            };
            else {
                w.WSynchro.windows = [window];
                w.WSynchro.source = window;
            }
            this.windows.push(w);
        }
        /** Trigger function
         *  @param {synchronize}
         *  @param {function} synchronize function
         */
        WSynchro.on = function (e, syncFn) {
            if (!this.syncFn_) this.syncFn_ = [];
            if (e === 'synchronize') this.syncFn_.push(syncFn);
        }
        /** Synchronize windows
         *  @param {Object|undefined} if undefined stop synchro (when the window is synchronize)
         */
        WSynchro.synchronize = function (params) {
            this.synchronize_(params);
        }
        /** Synchronize windows:
         *  @param {Array} array of arguments to use with fn
         *  @param {} internal syncrho time to avoid stnchro loops
         *  @private
         */
        WSynchro.synchronize_ = function (args, sync) {
            var i;
            // Stop condition
            if (!sync) {
                if (this.synchronizing) sync = this.sync;
                else this.sync = sync = (new Date()).getTime();
                this.synchronizing = false;
            } else { // Don't synchronize twice
                if (sync == this.sync) return;
                this.sync = sync;
                this.synchronizing = true;
                try {
                    if (WSynchro.syncFn_) {
                        args.type = "synchronize";
                        for (i = 0; i < WSynchro.syncFn_.length; i++) {
                            WSynchro.syncFn_[i].apply(null, [args]);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (e) { /* */ }
            }
            if (args)
                for (i = 0; i < this.windows.length; i++) {
                    try {
                        this.windows[i].WSynchro.synchronize_(args, sync);
                    } catch (e) { /* */ }
                }
        }

        // layer
        var stamen = new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.Stamen({
                layer: 'watercolor'
            })
        });

        // map
        var z = 6;
        pt = [270148, 6247782];
        rot = 0;
        // Window has a source -> get its position
        if (WSynchro.source) {
            z = WSynchro.source.map.getView().getZoom();
            pt = WSynchro.source.map.getView().getCenter();
            rot = WSynchro.source.map.getView().getRotation();
        }
        var map = new ol.Map({
            target: 'map',
            view: new ol.View({
                zoom: z,
                center: pt,
                rotation: rot
            }),
            layers: [stamen]
        });

        // Open a new window
        function openWin() {
            WSynchro.open();
        };

        // Synchronize function => set map position
        WSynchro.on('synchronize', function (e) {
            var view = map.getView();
            // Tell we are synchro
            if (e.pt == view.getCenter() && e.z == view.getZoom() && e.rot == view.getRotation()) {
                WSynchro.synchronize();
            }
            // Set position (will call WSynchro.synchronize on move end)
            else {
                view.setCenter(e.pt);
                view.setZoom(e.z);
                view.setRotation(e.rot || 0);
            }
        });

        // Synchronize on move / rotate
        map.on(['moveend', 'rotateend'], function (e) {
            var view = map.getView();
            WSynchro.synchronize({
                pt: view.getCenter(),
                z: view.getZoom(),
                rot: view.getRotation()
            });
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```